# Radio buttons disabled, not enabling even after selecting another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a radio select button where I want users to select a particular number for a particular topic. For example if the respondent selects Start-ups or agile new competitors = 1 then all the 1 for the subsequent topic be disabled.

I have achieved that functionality but however if I want to change the previously selected 1 option to some another option for the same topic I can do so but the 1 is not activated automatically as soon as select another option, it stays disabled.

[image]

Below is the picture of what I am trying to implement.. There you can see I have select 2 in the first option but still all the 1 radio buttons are disabled. I want the all 1 buttons to get activated as soon as I select other buttons.

Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".question tbody tr td").on('click', function () {
    var val,
        i,
        inputVal;
    $(this).addClass("checked");
    if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        val = document.querySelectorAll("td");
        val = Array.prototype.slice.call(val);
        val.splice(0,1);
        inputVal = $(this).find("input").val();
        $(".question tbody tr td").find("input[value="+inputVal+"]").attr('disabled',true);
    }
})
});
```

Adding the Table Structure.. Remember table structure can't be changed

```
    <tr id="javatbd572915X2X209SQ001" class="answers-list radio-list array2">
    <th class="answertext" width="20%">

        Start-Ups or agile new competitors
        <input type="hidden" name="java572915X2X209SQ001" id="java572915X2X209SQ001" value="1">

    </th>
    <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item" title="1">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1" value="1" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1">1</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item" title="2">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2" value="2" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2">2</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item" title="3">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3" value="3" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3">3</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item" title="4">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4" value="4" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4">4</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item" title="5">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5" value="5" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5">5</label>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: check you radio button has same 'name' value.

Comment: Yes for the same row.. Ex for all radio buttons of Start-Up topic its same, for flexible or mobile working its all same but its different for the topic itself. Ex if Startup has name of 5X4X then all the 1,2,3,4,5 buttons have same name.. In the same way if Flexible has name of 5X5X then all the 1,2,3,4,5 buttons of Flexible have same name..

Comment: can you add your radio button structure with question

Comment: not relevant checkconditions not required

Comment: Thanks. How about `val`? I see you get some elements, manipulate the list, but then never use it.

Comment: i had used it but now im confused what to do?? u have any solution to this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see is that you are disabling the new values (and checkboxes) without enabling the old ones. Right now your code does this when a cell is clicked:

1. Add `checked` class to the cell.
2. Disable all the `input`s with the new value.

You need to modify it so it does the following:

1. Remove the `checked` class to the currently checked cell
2. Enable all `input`s with the old value.
3. Add `checked` class to the current cell.
4. Disable all the `input`s with the new value.

So modifying as little as possible your code, it would look like this:

```js
function checkconditions() {
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question tbody tr td").on('click', function () {
        var val, i, inputVal;
        
        // reactivate the previously selected one (remove the check class)
        var prevSelected = $(this).parent().find(".checked").removeClass("checked").attr("title");
        if (prevSelected) {
            // enable again the checkboxes with that value
            $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='radio'][value='" + prevSelected + "']").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        
        // unmodified code
        $(this).addClass("checked");
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            val = document.querySelectorAll("td");
            val = Array.prototype.slice.call(val);
            val.splice(0,1);
            inputVal = $(this).find("input").val();
            $(".question tbody tr td").find("input[value="+inputVal+"]").attr('disabled',true);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="javatbd572915X2X209SQ001" class="answers-list radio-list array2">
        <th class="answertext" width="20%">

          Option 1
          <input type="hidden" name="java572915X2X209SQ001" id="java572915X2X209SQ001" value="1"/>

        </th>
        <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item" title="1">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1" value="1" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1">1</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item" title="2">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2" value="2" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2">2</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item" title="3">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3" value="3" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3">3</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item" title="4">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4" value="4" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4">4</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item" title="5">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5" value="5" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5">5</label>

        </td>
      </tr>



      <tr id="javatbd572915X2X209SQ001" class="answers-list radio-list array2">
        <th class="answertext" width="20%">

          Option 2
          <input type="hidden" name="java572915X2X209SQ001" id="java572915X2X209SQ001" value="1"/>

        </th>
        <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item" title="1">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ002" id="answer572915X2X209SQ002-1" value="1" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ002-1">1</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item" title="2">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ002" id="answer572915X2X209SQ002-2" value="2" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ002-2">2</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item" title="3">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ002" id="answer572915X2X209SQ002-3" value="3" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ002-3">3</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item" title="4">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ002" id="answer572915X2X209SQ002-4" value="4" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ002-4">4</label>

        </td>
        <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item" title="5">

          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ002" id="answer572915X2X209SQ002-5" value="5" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"/><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ002-5">5</label>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can also see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93o83jsu/

Comment: As I commented above, `val` is unused and unnecessary in the code (at least not in this snippet). I just left it so I kept your code as close to the original as possible (in case you use it somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove class "checked" in all row before do action "click"
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question tbody tr td").on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('td').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        //you do not need if expr because it will always true
        $(this).find("input").attr('disabled',true);
    });
});
```

But... for why? You can just use "name" attribute in radio inputs and css-selector :checked for it.

Comment: because.. I am modifying a lime survey question and adding this behavior if any radio button is chosed for example if 1 is selected then disable 1 for all the actions.. Lime survey assigns the class `checked` in the `td` element everytime i select a buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $cellSelector=$("#myTable tr td");
$cellSelector.on('click', function () {
  
  var val,
        i,
        inputVal;
    $(this).addClass("checked");
    if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        val = document.querySelectorAll("td");
        val = Array.prototype.slice.call(val);
        val.splice(0,1);
        inputVal = $(this).find("input").val();
       
      
      $cellSelector.find("input[value="+inputVal+"]")
      .attr('disabled',true);
      
      // To enable all other checkboxes
      $cellSelector.find("input:not([value="+inputVal+"])")
        .attr('disabled',false);
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
<table id="myTable">

<tr id="javatbd572915X2X209SQ001" class="answers-list radio-list array2">
    <th class="answertext" width="20%">

        Start-Ups or agile new competitors
        <input type="hidden" name="java572915X2X209SQ001" id="java572915X2X209SQ001" value="1">

    </th>
    <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item" title="1">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1" value="1" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1">1</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item" title="2">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2" value="2" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2">2</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item" title="3">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3" value="3" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3">3</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item" title="4">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4" value="4" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4">4</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item" title="5">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5" value="5" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5">5</label>

    </td>
</tr>
  
<tr id="javatbd572915X2X209SQ001" class="answers-list radio-list array2">
    <th class="answertext" width="20%">

     Some other Topic
        <input type="hidden" name="java572915X2X209SQ002" id="java572915X2X209SQ001" value="1">
   </th>
    <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item" title="1">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1" value="1" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-1">1</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item" title="2">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2" value="2" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-2">2</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item" title="3">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3" value="3" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-3">3</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item" title="4">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4" value="4" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-4">4</label>

    </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item" title="5">

        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="572915X2X209SQ001" id="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5" value="5" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><label class="hide read" for="answer572915X2X209SQ001-5">5</label>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please try this out

Comment: If I check the first answer and then again I check the second answer, it unchecks my first answer check .. I want the first answer to remain as it is.. For example for start ups if i select 1 then the 1 for some other topic be disabled while the rest are enabled, I should be able to check someother topic radio box without unchecking the start ups radio button.. Right now I can only check one answer..

Comment: And the other tr has different id